# Is there a way to save the inputs and functionalities of your HTML code without using a database?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple reviewer using HTML and JavaScript. Basically, I want to take notes from the PDFs uploaded by my teachers while also being able to review them. The answers are highlighted with black so that they are initially covered, with the highlights removed upon mouse enter. I want to be able to save my progress so that when I reload, all the inputs and the functionalities are still retained, like the remove button and the mouse enter and leave functionalities. Is there a way to do this without using a database? Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .question {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .highlight {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple Reviewer</h1>

  <label for="question">Question:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="question" name="question" size="50" required />
  <br>
  <label for="answer">Answer:</label>
  <br>
  <textarea id="answer" name="answer" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="getQuestion()">Enter</button>
  <br>
  <h2>Questions</h2>
  <div id="questionContainer"></div>

  <script>
    function getQuestion() {
      var questionText = document.getElementById("question").value;
      var answerText = document.getElementById("answer").value;

      if (questionText.trim() !== "" && answerText.trim() !== "") {
        var questionContainer = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
        var questionDiv = document.createElement("div");
        questionDiv.className = "question";
        questionDiv.textContent = questionText;
        questionContainer.appendChild(questionDiv);

        var answerDiv = document.createElement("pre"); 
        answerDiv.textContent = answerText;
        answerDiv.className = "answer highlight";
        questionContainer.appendChild(answerDiv);

        answerDiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
          answerDiv.classList.remove("highlight");
        });

        answerDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
          answerDiv.classList.add("highlight");
        });

        var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
        removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
        removeButton.onclick = function () {
          questionContainer.removeChild(questionDiv);
          questionContainer.removeChild(answerDiv);
          questionContainer.removeChild(removeButton);
        };

        questionContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
        questionContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        document.getElementById("question").value = "";
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
      }
    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried saving it all by using Inspect Element, copying it and then saving it as a new HTML file, the texts are saved, but all the functions do not work.

Comment: localStorage or indexeddb

Comment: It may be worth taking a quick step back and checking out some basic web/HTTP tutorials as well to clear up some confusion.

Comment: You can store data in a variety of places.  For in-browser storage you have `localStorage`.  You could also potentially use an online database (if the reason you don't want to use one is because you don't want to install and manage one).  You could potentially save data to a file (though the experience of saving/reading a file with in-browser JavaScript may not be what you expect).  What seems *more* of a concern here is that you appear to be describing *saving the HTML page itself*, which is kind of strange.  Save *data* which represents the state of the page, and code should use that data.

Comment: indexeddb is available to Javascript but I think the db stands for database. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#

Comment: @QuentinUK I don’t think the OP is aware of client-based storage or DBs and actually means an external DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various of techniques like `cookies`, `localStorage` etc.

I personally prefer to use `localStorage` which is easy `set` and get values.

```js
// Set a value
localStorage.setItem("question", "My Question ...");

// Get a value
localStorage.getItem("question");
```

---

For implementation of your example, I suggest you to use `localStorage.setItem` in your `getQuestion()` function then call it as you want, I added it to a button click for better understanding.

```js
function setQuestion() {
  let question = localStorage.getItem("question");
  let answer = localStorage.getItem("answer");

  document.querySelector('input[name="question"]').value = question;
  document.querySelector('textarea[name="answer"]').value  = answer;
}


function getQuestion() {
  var questionText = document.getElementById("question").value;
  var answerText = document.getElementById("answer").value;

  localStorage.setItem("question", questionText); // HERE
  localStorage.setItem("answer", answerText); // HERE


  if (questionText.trim() !== "" && answerText.trim() !== "") {
    var questionContainer = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
    var questionDiv = document.createElement("div");
    questionDiv.className = "question";
    questionDiv.textContent = questionText;
    questionContainer.appendChild(questionDiv);

    var answerDiv = document.createElement("pre");
    answerDiv.textContent = answerText;
    answerDiv.className = "answer highlight";
    questionContainer.appendChild(answerDiv);

    answerDiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
      answerDiv.classList.remove("highlight");
    });

    answerDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
      answerDiv.classList.add("highlight");
    });

    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
    removeButton.onclick = function () {
      questionContainer.removeChild(questionDiv);
      questionContainer.removeChild(answerDiv);
      questionContainer.removeChild(removeButton);
    };

    questionContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
    questionContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    document.getElementById("question").value = "";
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.question {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .highlight {
      background-color: black;
    }
```

```html
  <h1>Simple Reviewer</h1>

  <label for="question">Question:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="question" name="question" size="50" required value="myquestion" />
  <br>
  <label for="answer">Answer:</label>
  <br>
  <textarea id="answer" name="answer" rows="4" cols="50" required>myanswer</textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="getQuestion()">Enter</button>
  <br>
  <h2>Questions</h2>
  <div id="questionContainer"></div>

  <br><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="setQuestion()">Set My Values</button>
```